# Accessory View out of visible range of UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit, ios

I create custom UITableViewCell and just put the Accessory Type to Disclosure Button

```
cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDetailDisclosureButton;
```

But the half Accessory is out of the View on the right border of the screen.
Sadly, but I can not post a screenshot because I need 10 posts to do that.

I searched everywhere but I did not found anything about this problem.

Comment: You could just post a link to an image, using a service like Photobucket or Cloud App.

Comment: Or use imgur, which is the same service the built-in image-upload button uses.

Comment: Ah yes good idea.
There is a screenshot: http://imgur.com/nA1mS.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are not allowed to change the width if UITableViewCell the problem here may be with the width of UITableView itself.

Try adjusting the `tableView.frame.size.width` to fit the main window/screen width.
You can also check the width of parent views if there are any.

Comment: Oh I am embarrassed, the problem was just that I resized the Tableview out of the bound of the visible area of the view and half of the Accessory area was out.